# Redirection to an external website in a Portlet

Tags: url, redirect, portlet

I have a portlet where the `doView` method calls the `display.jsp` page with the following instruction :

```
getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/views/display.jsp").dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

In the `display.jsp`, I want to do a redirection to an external website :

```
<%
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.fr");
%>
```

Why is it not working at all ?
(I put a `<div>foobar<div>` in the JSP to see if that works and it does)
Is there another solution to make a redirection to an external URL ?

(The idea is to "stay" in the portlet/portal where the user can see the "targetted" website)

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Page 141 of the [Portlet 2.0 specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286) , it mentions that HttpServletRespone#sendRedirect() is a NO-OP in the render phase.

So that is the reason why you don't see this working. As per the semantics, the response object is a HttpServletResponse which corresponds to the response for the whole page and not just the portlet to which this JSP belongs. Since the page is now a composition of multiple portlets and each portlet having it's own lifecycle, you should be using one of the renderResponse, actionResponse objects and avoid using the servlet objects.

I am yet to find a solution for your original problem though.